# JQuery if statement conditions

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

I've got a function that slides a div horizontally by manipulating the left value.  Everything works well I can get it to scroll right and left just fine, what I'm having problem with is my if statements i believe and stopping it from scrolling.  I'm measuring the left value of the div and I know the lower and upper limit that it should moved based upon div and screen measurements.  But it wont stop scrolling even when the left value is far greater than the limits in either direction.  Also the first if statement tests if the panels are even hidden and need to be scrolled, thats what the panelsWidth and portWidth variables are for.  Not sure if my variables aren't getting updated or what, any suggestions?  Thanks ahead of time.

JQuery Code

```
function portfolioSlider() {

var portWidth = $(window).width()-440;
var panelsWidth = panels * 221;
var portDifference = panelsWidth - portWidth;

if (panelsWidth < portWidth) {
}

else if(panelsWidth > portWidth) {

    var leftPosition = $('#web').css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    var upperLimit = 220;
    var lowerLimit = 220 - portDifference;
    var hoverInterval;

    if(leftPosition >= lowerLimit, leftPosition <= upperLimit) {

        $(".arrow_right").css('display','block').css('opacity','1')
        $(".arrow_left").css('display','block').css('opacity','1')          
        $(".arrow_right").hover(
            function() {
                hoverInterval = setInterval(
                function() {
                    $('#web').css('left','-=2');
                    leftPosition = $('#web').css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
                },10);
            },
            function() {
                clearInterval(hoverInterval);
            }
        );
        $(".arrow_left").hover(
            function() {
                hoverInterval = setInterval(
                function() {
                    $('#web').css('left','+=2');
                    leftPosition = $('#web').css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
                },10);
            },
            function() {
                clearInterval(hoverInterval);
            }
        );          
    }       
    else {
    }       
};
};

portfolioSlider()
```

the HTML is really irrelevant its just a div with image panels in it, that works fine.  Again thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use jQuery.animate()? You can just as easily do something like

```
$(".arrow_right").hover(
    function() { this.animate("left", animateTo); },
    function() { this.animate("left", animateFrom); }
);
```

Comment: The whole animate and sliding of the div works fine, I'm more concerned with getting the function and if statement to actually stop working when the conditions aren't met anymore.  I had it setup to display the left value as i scrolled and the variable was changing according to how it was getting scrolled.  Problem is once the left value goes past the designated max or min it just continues to scroll even if you move off of the hot spot and back onto it.

Comment: That's why I suggest using the jquery animate functions to do the animation for you. There might be a bunch of things happening that you might not be noticing (including converting css pixel values (which you can do with parseInt), your Intervals maybe not getting reset, css values getting changed when you don't want them to, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 if(leftPosition >= lowerLimit, leftPosition <= upperLimit) {
```

is not valid Javascript.

Did you mean boolean **AND**?

```
 if(leftPosition >= lowerLimit && leftPosition <= upperLimit) {
```

i.e. in mathematical notation: `lowerLimit <= leftPosition  <= upperLimit`